# Numpy Structured Arrays by Name AND Index

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I can never seem to get NumPy arrays to work nicely for me. :(

My dataset is simple: 150 rows of 4 floats followed by one string. I tried the following:

```
data = np.genfromtxt("iris.data2", delimiter=",", names=["SL", "SW", "PL", "PW", "class"], dtype=[float, float, float, float, '|S16'])

print(data.shape) ---> (150, 0)
print(data["PL"])
print(data[:, 0:3]) <---error
```

So I changed it just 5 floats by doing a simple file replace. I only do this because I couldn't get the non-homogenous array to work nicely with both column name and index accessing. But now that I have made it homogenous, it still gives me back a shape of (150, 0) and an error.

```
data = np.genfromtxt("iris.data", delimiter=",", names=["SL", "SW", "PL", "PW", "class"])

print(data.shape) ---> (150, 0)
print(data["PL"])
print(data[:, 0:3]) <--- error
```

When I remove the names entirely, it works for index-column acces, but obviously not names anymore.

```
data = np.genfromtxt("iris.data", delimiter=",")

print(data.shape) ---> (150, 5)
# print(data["PL"])
print(data[:, 0:3]) ---> WORKS GREAT!!!
```

Why is this and how do I fix it? Ideally I would like both name and index column access without replacing the string with a float-code, but I will do it if I need to in order to get name and index column access.

Comment: Have you considered [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/)?

Comment: What jonrsharpe said.  If you're working with actual data, if you stick with structured arrays you'll find yourself reimplementing DataFrame functionality yourself instead of getting on with whatever it is you really wanted to do.

Comment: So it is not feasibly possible to get both named columns and indexed columns access in just NumPy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a clear distinction between the fields of a 1d structured array, and the columns of a 2d array.  They aren't interchangeable.  Field names aren't simply column labels.  If that isn't clear you many need to read the `dtype` or `structured array` docs in more detail.

Define a pseudo file:

```
In [93]: txt=b"""1,2,3,4,txt
   ....: 5,6,7,8,abc"""

In [94]: np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(),delimiter=',',dtype=None)
Out[94]: 
array([(1, 2, 3, 4, 'txt'), (5, 6, 7, 8, 'abc')], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4'), ('f2', '<i4'), ('f3', '<i4'), ('f4', 'S3')])
```

With mixed columns the default way to load it is a structured array, with 2 rows (shape=(2,)), and 5 fields, indexed as `data['f0']` or `data[['f0','f2']]`.  The ability to index several fields at once is limited.

But we can define a compound dtype, such as:

```
In [102]: dt=np.dtype([('data',float,(4,)),('lbl','|S5')])

In [103]: dt
Out[103]: dtype([('data', '<f8', (4,)), ('lbl', 'S5')])

In [104]: np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(),delimiter=',',dtype=dt)
Out[104]: 
array([([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0], 'txt'), ([5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0], 'abc')], 
      dtype=[('data', '<f8', (4,)), ('lbl', 'S5')])

In [105]: data=np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(),delimiter=',',dtype=dt)

In [106]: data['data']
Out[106]: 
array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.],
       [ 5.,  6.,  7.,  8.]])

In [107]: data['lbl']
Out[107]: 
array(['txt', 'abc'], 
      dtype='|S5')

In [108]: data[0]
Out[108]: ([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0], 'txt')
```

Now `data['data']` is a 2d array, containing the numeric values from the original text.

---

The field names can be fetched as a tuple:

```
In [112]: data.dtype.names
Out[112]: ('data', 'lbl')
```

so it is possible to perform usual list/tuple indexing on them, and even do something a convoluted as viewing the fields in reverse order:

```
In [115]: data[list(data.dtype.names[::-1])]
Out[115]: 
array([('txt', [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]), ('abc', [5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0])], 
      dtype=[('lbl', 'S5'), ('data', '<f8', (4,))])
```

Comment: I had not realized that there was not a correlation between structured arrays's fields and multi-dimensional arrays columns. Compound data types are a bit over-complicated for this problem. I just changed the strings to floats, and am using only index accessing. Then when I want something by name, I have a name->index dictionary to grab the right index for that column name. Anything horribly wrong with that? haha

Comment: Or try `usecols` to load just the numeric columns: `np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(),delimiter=',',usecols=range(4))`

Answer (score 1):

once you pass a sequence or a single-string of comma-separated names to names parameter, then the data you get is a one dimensional array. That's why data[:, 0:3] won't work

```
In[95]: data = np.genfromtxt("datasets\iris.csv", delimiter=",", \
                     names=["SL", "SW", "PL", "PW", "class"], \
                     dtype=[float, float, float, float, '|S16'])
data.shape
Out[95]: (151,)

In[96]: data = np.genfromtxt("datasets\iris.csv", delimiter=",")
data.shape
Out[96]: (151, 6)
```