# genfromtxt names changes the shape of the array

Tags: python, numpy

I am importing a decent amount of data from a CSV file. The original CSV file has around 40 columns, I am trimming it down and want to use my own names (as shown below) for column names.

```
import numpy as np
import math
import sys
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

print(sys.argv)
data1 = np.genfromtxt(
sys.argv[1], 
skip_header=10,
skip_footer=1, 
delimiter=',',
usecols=(0,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27),
names=['line','TPS','mph','rpm','load','engtemp','trq','month','day','T1','T2','T3','T4','T5','T6','T7','T8','T9','T10','T11','T12','T13','T14','T15','T16'])
```

Unfortunately this changes the shape of the array and I don't know how to compensate for it, neither do I know how to call out the names. Originally I was hoping that it would save each column as it's own list with the name specified. If you know of a function that does that, that would be neat!

So, the question. 
Why does the above not work when I try to reference a column for plotting

```
plt.plot(data1[:,9])
```

but when I remove the names argument from genfromtxt it works fine?

and

is there a way to do something like? 
    plt.plot(data1[T1])

Could it be because the 'names' argument is trying to name the rows, not the columns?
When names is used I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "HeatReport.py", line 48, in <module>
    print(data1[3,9])
IndexError: too many indices for array
```

Comment: With `names` it is loading the data as a 1d `structured` array.  Look at its `dtype`.  Read the docs on dtype and structured. It's also a frequent SO question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/35259650/901925